Can you be an astrologer's disciple?
In mahabharata it is mentioned that an astrologer is equal to a bramha hanta..can you learn other vidyas from astrologer(apart from astrology)? Are there any examples of astrologer's disciples?
Mahabharata 5 udyoga parva section XXXV[
